# AngularJS http.jsonp can't find JSON_CALLBACK from custom PHP proxy response

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, proxy

I'm trying to get a simple JSON reply from Readability, which works ok using the direct link to Readability's API, eg:

```
$http.jsonp('https://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser?url='+url+'&token='+token+'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data) { ... etc
```

But doesn't work when using my own "proxy":

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    print file_get_contents('https://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser?url='.urlencode($_GET['url']).'&token='.$token.'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
?>
```

with:

```
$http.jsonp('parser.php?url='+url).success(function(data) { ...
```

I've also tried it with curl and duplicating all of the headers, etc. I don't get it, how come http.jsonp can't find the variable JSON_CALLBACK from my own proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON_CALLBACK` is replaced during the call to `angular.callbackSomething` and your PHP uses hardcoded `JSON_CALLBACK` so when angular tries to run `callbackSomething` there is no function from jsonp with this method, hope that makes sense

```
print file_get_contents('https://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser?url='.urlencode($_GET['url']).'&token='.$token.'&callback='.$_GET['callback']);
```